# A PostgreSQL function to return computed string from joined tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables.

```
Table A   |   Table B   |   Table C
----------|-------------|------------
name      |   name      |   name
phrase    |   phrase    |   phrase
field 1   |   include   |   include
field 2   |   exclude   |   exclude
field 3   |   field 1   |   field 1
```

Table A, B, C contains a lot of other columns too but i am interested in only `Table B (include and exclude)` and `Table C (include and exclude)`.

I am trying to write a function which will take `name` and `phrase` of Table A as parameter and make a query on `Table B` and `Table C` to get `include` and `exclude` columns of both tables where `Table B (name and phrase)` and `Table C (name and phrase)` are equal to parameters `name` and `phrase`.

The include and exclude columns are boolean and i want to use the `B.include`, `B.exclude`, `C.include` and `C.exclude` to return a string.

What i have written so far is but i am not sure if it is right.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createString(name text, phrase text) RETURNS table (descp text) AS
$$
BEGIN

    select b.include, b.exclude, c.include, c.exclude
    from (TableB b join TableC c on b.name = c.name and b.phrase = c.phrase)
    where b.name = name and b.phrase = phrase;

    IF b.include = true THEN
        NEW := 'b included';
    ELSEIF b.exclude = true THEN
        NEW := 'b excluded';
    ELSEIF c.exclude = true THEN
        NEW := 'c excluded';
    ELSEIF c.exclude = true THEN
        NEW := 'c excluded';
    END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am new to writing functions and don't really know if i am doing it right. Can someone please help me point in right direction.

Comment: It's really unclear what you need exactly. The function `RETURNS table`, but the (invalid) body tries to return a single value. What do you need *exactly? Start by declaring the version of Postgres in use and providing proper table definitions showing data types and constraints (`CREATE TABLE` scripts). See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still learning and what i wrote in original question was learn and trial code. I ended up writing something like this....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createString(name text, phrase text) RETURNS TEXT AS
$$
DECLARE
    moInclude boolean;
    moExcluded boolean;
    modaidInclude boolean;
    modaidExclude boolean;
    result text := 'None';
BEGIN
    select mo.include, mo.exclude, modaid.include, modaid.exclude INTO moInclude, moExcluded, modaidInclude, modaidExclude
    from (tableB AS mo JOIN tableC AS modaid on mo.text = modaid.text and mo.phrase = modaid.phrase)
    where mo.text = text and mo.phrase = phrase;

    IF moInclude = true AND modaidInclude = true THEN
        result := 'INCLUDED';
    ELSEIF (moExcluded = true) THEN
        result := 'EXCLUDED';
    ELSEIF ((moInclude = false AND modaidInclude = true AND modaidExclude = false) OR
        (moInclude = false AND modaidInclude = false AND modaidExclude = true) OR
        (moInclude = true AND modaidInclude = false AND modaidExclude = true) OR
        (moInclude = true AND modaidInclude = false AND modaidExclude = false)) THEN
        result := 'PARTIAL';
    ELSE
        result := 'NONE';
    END IF;

RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Calling this function when i am creating a view.

Thank you everyone for help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend that you write a function for this.  Functions tend to be performance killers.

Instead, you can write a view, using `left join` to bring the tables together:

For the logic you have written, you seem to want:

```
select a.*,
       (case when b.include then 'B included' 
             when b.exclude then 'B excluded' 
             when c.include then 'C included' 
             when c.exclude then 'C excluded' 
        end) as string
from a left join
     b
     on a.name = b.name and a.phrase = b.phrase left join
     c
     on a.name = c.name and a.phrase = c.phrase;
```

This returns the first match on the flag.  I might expect that you want the strings concatenated together in some way, but that is not the pseudo-code you have written.

Comment: I have to write the function and the reason is that i have a view. In that view i am creating a column which will be populated with the value of this function.

Comment: @AGilani You can just add the CASE statement to the view.

Comment: @AGilani . . . If this is for a view, that is all the more reason why you *don't* need a function.  You can incorporate the logic into the view.

Answer (score 0):

@GordonLinoff is correct that this wold be better just using SQL instead of a function. But if you must have a function then you can create a SQL Function - function with [language sql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html). The following converts your last function and reproduces it as a SQL Function. 
Additionally since the columns Include and Exclude already defined as boolean, they don't need equal evacuation. That is "if include ..." will produce the same result as "if include = true". But for false values you need to negate the value so "if include = false" becomes simply "not include". I've used that, but it could be easily replaced.

```
-- create tables and gen test data 
create table tableA (name text, phase text, field1 text, field2 text, field3 text) ;
create table TableB (name text, phase text, include boolean, exclude boolean, field1 text);
create table TableC (name text, phase text, include boolean, exclude boolean, field1 text);


insert into tableA (name,phase)
     values ('n1','p1') 
          , ('n2','p1') 
          , ('n3','p1') 
          , ('n4','p1')
          , ('n5','p1')
          , ('n6',null);           

insert into tableB(name, phase, include, exclude)
     values ('n1','p1',true,true)
          , ('n2','p1',true,false)
          , ('n3','p1',false,true)
          , ('n4','p1',false,false)
          , ('n5','p1',false,false);

insert into tableC(name, phase, include, exclude) 
     values ('n1','p1',true,true)
          , ('n2','p1',true,false)
          , ('n3','p1',false,true)
          , ('n4','p1',false,false) 
          , ('n5','p1',true,false);

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
create or replace function createString(name_in text, phase_in text) 
returns text
language sql strict
as $$
    select case when (mo.include and modaid.include)                                     then 'INCLUDED'
                when (mo.exclude)                                                        then 'EXCLUDED'
                when (   (not mo.include and modaid.include and not modaid.exclude)  
                      or (not mo.include and not modaid.include and modaid.exclude) 
                      or (mo.include     and not modaid.include and modaid.exclude) 
                      or (mo.include     and not modaid.include and not modaid.exclude)) then 'PARTIAL'
                else 'NONE' 
            end   
     from tableb as mo 
     join tablec as modaid on (    mo.name  = modaid.name 
                               and mo.phase = modaid.phase
                              )
    where mo.name  = name_in
      and mo.phase = phase_in
$$; 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- test
select name, phase, createString(name, phase) 
  from tableA;
```